# Visual difference with employee stats bar

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

I went to hire a new designer and this happened:
[image: Hire Staff window]

I've noticed this before, and it's always with characters who are very high in one stat over the other (Design/Technology). I wonder what it is supposed to mean, if anything.

**Is this a bug or is it a visual tip about the employee?**

Comment: I'm going to guess it's a bug.

Answer (score 2):

This is a visual bug - the numbers correctly detail the employee's skill level in Design and Technology but the bar renders incorrectly in the instance that an employee is highly skills in one but not the other.